# Validating plain observableArray()

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Assume my model is very simple (a list of strings), and I don't want to put typed objects into `observableArray` and [then validate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936527/how-to-validate-an-array) using deep validation `ko.validation.init( { grouping: { deep: true } } )`.

E.g. I want all array elements (which are plain strings) to comply with `minLength:3`.

Why `ko.observable().extend({minLength:3})` is OK, but `ko.observableArray().extend({minLength:3})` doesn't work?

Is there a workaround other than putting objects (instead of plain strings) into array?

Fiddle to [start with](http://jsfiddle.net/m6Jvk/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create a `minLength` function on the `observableArray` prototype like this:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.stringMinLength = function (minLength) {
    var self = this;// observableArray
    // Loop through array and apply logic to each element
    // Add subscriptions to the observableArray to determine what's been added (don't care about what's been removed)
    // In the subscriptions, deal with how to apply the minLength validation
    // -can't use '.extend({ minLength: minLength })' because these are plain strings, not observables
    return self;
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
var oa = ko.observableArray(["foo", "bar", "bo"]).stringMinLength(3);
```

The crux of your issue is how you want to apply validation to all the string elements when `oa`'s value has mutated.

Comment: oh that's too much for a simple extension of validation rules to members of observableArray... I'd better use artificial objects for my array which i can easily extend: `ko.observableArray([{value: ko.observable("foo").extend({minLength:3})}, ..., ...])`

Comment: Yeah, I would probably go with this as well.  You might look at the mapping plugin to map these objects in the array for you.  Or just create a simple constructor function that you pass in a string and an int that returns an object with a `value` property that's an observable, whose minLength is set to the int you pass.  `ko.observableArray([new Item('foo', 3), new Item('bar', 3), new Item('bo', 3), etc... ])`.  It's a blessing and a curse that there are a lot of ways to do the same thing.